# Let me know your availability

Tags: american-english, politeness, figures-of-speech, social-interaction

When someone suggests making a video call someday and you reply it is a good idea (even unsure he/she is just being polite) and he/she says let me know your availability, does he/she want to know the specific time range or can you just say "Will do"?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *Let me know your availability* directly equals "When are you ready for the video?" "Do you have a time slot someday soon for the video?" "Based on your calendar, when do you want to schedule it?" Business etiquette suggests looking at your calendar and offering two or three slots as your reply.

Also, *Would you like to dance?* means "Do you want to dance with me to this song?" [Shall We Dance?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QgVPnWmUqd4) If in 3/4 time, that means "Let's waltz, yes?" It is not an investigative request for information as to your general interest in dancing as a concept.

Answering *Will do* just wastes time since you already said it is "a good idea." Like when someone asks if you know the time, you would say what time it is, not *Yes, I do know the time.*

Comment: There's nothing wrong with saying "Will do" in this context if you don't know when you'll be available because you are not at your desk and can't yet check your diary/calendar.

Comment: The "will do" email is just another message the recipient has to process. Why not wait a couple of hours until you have info to share? This need to respond immediately (that is, with 10 minutes) to every email message ...

Comment: @nnnnnn "will do" works in IM, not email. In email, it is better for everyone to let it sit for a couple of hours and then answer when you have your calendar in front of you. Worst case scenario, you *still* shouldn't answer with a "will do", if you absolutely need to answer quickly, it should be something like "I'll get back at you at 15:00" or something indicating a time frame when your recipient can expect a more concrete answer

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza - I agree about email, but note that there is no mention of email in the question. The interaction the OP described sounds like an in-person conversation.

Comment: @nnnnnn "let me know your availability" is overtly formal for an in-person conversation, even between strangers, and it is an affirmation. In a in-person / phone conversation, this would be a question ("when would you be available?" / "what is your availability?") Even though OP doesn't mention, I'll put my money in written media, more specifically e-mail or other kind of messaging that's not instant, like LinkedIn messaging

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza - I have had people say "let me know your availability" in person and on the phone on numerous occasions. I'm not saying the expression isn't also used in writing, but it's definitely not limited to written communication.

Answer (score 0):

There is no absolute answer.  Economy of email (something too rare today) suggests you should tell him when you can talk.

I would read the reply as a (overly?) polite version of "Let me know when you're available," and I would do just that.  Otherwise, you'll need another round of email to confirm that you really want to talk, and then to home in on the time.  And do you really want more email?

Authority: inbox with 1,500 unread items, 20% of which Reply All to say, "Thank you."

Comment: You're assuming the exchange takes place by email, but the question doesn't say so. The conversation described could have been in-person or on the phone.

Comment: But if you're already talking, why would you be talking about when you can talk?  I'll give that it could be an IM, but this doesn't make sense if it's a real-time exchange.

Comment: I have had numerous in-person conversations in which a plan was made to meet again at some later date that is not yet confirmed, with both parties saying they'll check their schedule and get back to the other. This has occurred in both business and personal contexts. It's not unusual.

Comment: I've fallen victim to the pre-meet, the meeting to discuss the meeting. I think less of myself each time. After all, I'm using I could be reading ELU!